# Compare values of two arrays in julia

Tags: julia

I have two integer arrays that I need to compare. The output of the comparison of `sequenceOne = [1, 3, 2, 1]` and `sequenceTwo = [1, 3, 2, 1]` should be true. Is there a method for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `==`:

```
julia> sequenceOne = [1, 3, 2, 1];

julia> sequenceTwo = [1, 3, 2, 1];

julia> sequenceOne == sequenceTwo
true
```

Alternatively, if you are looking to compare elementwise then you can broadcast `==` with a `.`

```
julia> sequenceOne .== sequenceTwo
4-element BitArray{1}:
 true
 true
 true
 true
```

Comment: Nice answer, adding the broadcast `.==` for element-by-element comparisons.